# Quick way for the expected first hitting time for a 2D Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $\{W_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ be a standard 2D Brownian motion starting at $(1,1)\in\Bbb R^2$. What's the probability that $W_t$ hits the positive half of $x$-axis before it hits the negative part?

There are standard "tricks" to solve similar problems in 1D. For example, if $B_t$ is a standard 1D BM starting at 0 and we want to compute $\Bbb P(B_t\,\text{hits 3 before hitting -5})$, then we let $\tau=\inf\{t\ge 0\mid B_t=3\vee B_t=-5\}$ and since $\tau$ is a.s. bounded we have, by the optional stopping theorem, that
$$0=B_0=\Bbb E(B_\tau)=\Bbb E(B_\tau I(B_\tau = 3))+\Bbb E(B_\tau I(B_\tau = -5))=3\Bbb P(B_\tau=3)-5(1-\Bbb P(B_\tau = 3)).$$
Simple as above. We don't have to explicitly work out the distribution or expectation of $\tau$ at all.

Now back to the 2D case. Do similar elegant tricks exist? If not, what'd be the quickest possible way to solve it? (For what it's worth, this problem was asked in a Morgan Stanley quant interview, so I expect there to be at least one trick that can solve it in no more than a few minutes.)

Comment: Nice question. Do you happen to have more examples of this nature?

Comment: @Calculon most for-interview stopping time questions I encountered are about 1D Brownian motion, which in most cases can be elegantly solved with simple applications of optional stopping theorem (otherwise would be too hard for an interview). This 2D version is actually much more difficult than most interview questions and perhaps a rational interviewer wouldn't be interested in asking anything beyond this level. Of course if we also count harder than interview kind of questions we can make them arbitrarily hard like finding the P of an nD BM hits region A before hitting B...

Comment: @Calculon ...but then most of them would be intractable, right?

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is hard to find nontrivial yet accessible problems on this topic. It is even harder with the extra requirement the problem be solvable in a relatively small amount of time. I think the kind of problems you described would mostly be intractable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complement to the answer posted by @saz that does not require an explicit use of the distribution of the stopping time. I will just use the notation in that answer. We want to compute $P\{B_{\tau}^1 \geq -1\}$. Since $B^1$ and $\tau$ are independent, we can write

$$P\{B_{\tau}^1 \leq -1\} = \int_{t\geq 0} P\{B_t^1 \leq -1\}f_{\tau}(t)\,dt$$
where $f_{\tau}(t)$ is the density of $\tau$. By the reflection principle,

$$P\{\tau \leq t\} = P\{N^2_t \leq -1\} = P\{M^2_t \geq 1\} = P\{\lvert B^2_t\rvert \geq 1\} = 2P\{B^2_t \leq -1\} = 2P\{B^1_t \leq -1\}$$
where $N^2$ and $M^2$ are the running minimum and the running maximum of $B^2$, respectively.

We can then write $f_{\tau}(t)\,dt = 2 dP\{B^1_t \leq -1\}$. Hence, the integral we want to evaluate becomes

$$2\int_{t\geq 0} P\{B_t^1 \leq -1\}dP\{B^1_t \leq -1\} = \left. P\{B_t^1 \leq -1\}^2\right|_{t=0}^{t=\infty} = \lim_{t\to\infty} P\left\{B_1^1 \leq -\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right\}^2 = P\left\{B_1^1 \leq 0\right\}^2 = \frac{1}{4}$$

The last but one step uses dominated convergence.

Comment: Why are $B^1$ and $\tau$ independent?

Comment: @Vim $B^1$ and $B^2$ are independent processes.

Comment: I suppose it might need more clarification to justify $\{\tau\le t\}\in \sigma(B_2^s, s\le t)$.

Comment: @Vim Circular argument perhaps but $\tau$ is a stopping time and hence $\{\tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ with $\mathcal{F}$ being the canonical filtration generated by $B^2$. If you want to know why $\tau$ is a stopping time, that is probably in every text book / online lecture notes on stochastic processes.

Comment: I know $\tau$ is a stopping time, but I don't know why $F$ is generated by $B^2$ only but not jointly by $B^1, B^2$. In other words, how to show $\tau$ doesn't also depend on $B^1$?

Comment: @Vim Hitting times are stopping times with respect to the canonical filtration (under some conditions on the regularity of the paths and the hitting sets). $\tau$ is a hitting time defined in terms of $B^2$ only.

Comment: So you're using saz's definition of $\tau$. I see. Thanks. Just now I was thinking about a different definition. But now its clear.

Comment: Very nice. I learned a useful relationship $M_t=_d |B_t|$ :)

Comment: @Vim I am glad it helped :)

Answer (score 5):

The two-dimensional Brownian motion $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has components which are independent Brownian motions, i.e. $$W_t = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} +\begin{pmatrix} B_t^1 \\ B_t^2 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $(B_t^i)_{t \geq 0}$, $i=1,2$, are independent one-dimensional Brownian motions started at $0$. Your problem boils down to finding  $\mathbb{P}(1+B_{\tau}^1 \geq 0)$ for the stopping time

$$\tau := \inf\{t \geq 0; (1,1)+(B_t^1,B_t^2) \in \mathbb{R} \times (-\infty,0]\}.$$

Clearly,

$$\tau = \inf\{t \geq 0; 1+B_t^2 \leq 0\}$$

which means that $\tau$ is a stopping time with respect to the canonical filtration $\mathcal{F}_t^{2} := \sigma(B_s^2; s \leq t)$. In particular, $\tau$ is independent from $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}^{1} := \sigma(B_s^1; s \geq 0)$. Hence,

$$p:=\mathbb{P}(1+B_{\tau}^1 \geq 0) = \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \mathbb{P}(1+B_t^1 \geq 0) \bigg|_{t=\tau} \bigg].$$

It is known from the reflection principle that $\tau$ has distribution $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}} \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2t} \right) 1_{(0,\infty)}(t) \, dt$$ and therefore we get

$$\begin{align*} p &= \int_0^{\infty} \int_{-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t^3}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left(- \frac{1}{2t} - \frac{y^2}{2t} \right) \, dy \, dt \\ &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-1}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \exp \left(- \frac{1+y^2}{2t} \right) \frac{dt}{t^2} \, dy \\ &= \int_{-1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+y^2} \, dy \\ &=  \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \arctan(-1). \end{align*}$$

**Remark:** The above calculation actually shows that $B_{\tau}^1$ is standard Cauchy distributed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be easily able to convert this 2D problem into a 1D one. An intuitive explanation follows.

Converting to polar coordinates, the motion is individually brownian in both $\theta$ and $r$. We don't really care about the $r$ in this case. We see that the current $\theta$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$. The problem is basically asking which angle among $0$ and $\pi$ will we hit first. Use the exact same formula you quoted for the 1D case and you should get your answer.

Comment: It's not trivial to show $\theta$ and $r$ are independently Brownian, I think.